# If you separate the typescript classes by files, then an error occurs. How can this be?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

In what there can be an error?
When all classes are in the same file, the error does not appear.
But as soon as I place the classes in different files, the following errors appear:

> /index2.ts(8,13): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ name: string;
>   value: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConfigOption
>   | ConfigOption[]'.   Type '{ name: string; value: number; }' is not
>   assignable to type 'ConfigOption[]'.
>       Property 'length' is missing in type '{ name: string; value: number; }'.
>
> /index2.ts(14,12): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ name: string;
>   value: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'ConfigOption[]'.   Type '{ name: string; value: string; }' is not
>   assignable to type 'ConfigOption'.
>       Property 'comment' is missing in type '{ name: string; value: string; }'. 17:36:36 - Compilation complete. Watching for file
>   changes.

```
interface IOption {
    name: string;
    value?: any;
    comment?: string;
}

class ConfigOption {
    name: string;
    value: any;
    comment: string;
    constructor(data: IOption) {}
}

type TOptionArray = (IOption | ConfigOption)[];

class Config {
    constructor(options?: TOptionArray) {}
    push(data: ConfigOption | IOption | TOptionArray) {}
}

// Test example:

const config = new Config;

config.push({
    name: 'name',
    value: 0
});


new Config([{
    name: 'role',
    value: 'camelcase(this.element.name)'
}]);
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0ergcw4pt88oeu/typescriptproblem.zip?dl=0

Layout of the code by files:

```
// config/Config.ts

import IOption from './option/ConfigOption';
import ConfigOption from './option/ConfigOption';

export type TOptionArray = (IOption | ConfigOption)[];

export default class Config {
    constructor(options?: TOptionArray) {}
    push(data: ConfigOption | IOption | TOptionArray) {}
}

// config/option/ConfigOption.ts

import Config from '../Config';

export interface IOption {
    name: string;
    value?: any;
    comment?: string;
}

export default class ConfigOption {
    name: string;
    value: any;
    comment: string;
    constructor(data: IOption) {}
}


// index2.ts

import Config from './config/Config';

const config = new Config;

config.push({
    name: 'name',
    value: 0
});


new Config([{
    name: 'role',
    value: 'camelcase(this.element.name)'
}]);
```

Comment: What does it look like when it's split into two files? How do you separate the files?

Comment: @Aron In the archive there is an example where the files are separated.

Comment: I don't want to download a zip archive. Please just post your code in two blocks.

Comment: @Louis There are no errors. The problem disappears if all classes are simply copied into one file.

Comment: @Aron I changed the post. Added code for files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are not importing correctly.**

You should change `config/option/ConfigOption.ts` to remove the default export:

```
export class ConfigOption { // Removed the `default` keyword.
```

And in `config/Config.ts`, import like this:

```
import { IOption, ConfigOption } from './option/ConfigOption';
```

In my own code I've completely banished default exports to avoid mistakes like this. You could keep the default export but I don't recommend it.

---

The way you had it, was like this:

```
import IOption from './option/ConfigOption';
import ConfigOption from './option/ConfigOption';
```

This imports the default export from `./option/ConfigOption.ts` and assigns it locally to both to `IOption` and `ConfigOption`. So your `IOption` did not correspond to the `IOption` in `./option/ConfigOption.ts` but instead it was corresponding to the default export of that module which is `ConfigOption`.

Answer (score -1):

You can just leave out the export and import keywords, those are not necessary, even if you work with separate .ts files.

Unless you want to work with modules or namespaces, but it seems that you don't want that?

Comment: Can I talk about modules afterwards? Now I would like to deal with this error))

Comment: Like I said, you can just leave out import and export and it will work. import and export are only used for modules.